# Is an object not GC'd even if it has references to other object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

I thought that an object is eligible for Garbage Collection once it is not referenced by any other thing (object or variable).
ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144938

But In Java linked list [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.unlinkFirst%28java.util.LinkedList.Node%29)

[image]

Here not only the author removes any references to it, but he also goes on to remove what it refers to .
Why is this needed ?
Am I missing something in my understanding about Garbage Collection ?

Comment: [`unlinkLast()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.unlinkLast%28java.util.LinkedList.Node%29) has a similar quirk: `l.prev = null; // help GC`

Comment: Say that more than one element is removed through repeated calls to `unlinkFirst()`. The garbage collector *could*  collect them all, but it does quite an effort (in the so-called train algorithm) to keep track of which objects are eligible for collection in such cases. My guess is it’s easier and hence less costly to collect them one at a time without caring about references from other eligible objects.

Comment: This _isn't_ needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't LinkedList.Clear() O(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161031/why-isnt-linkedlist-clear-o1)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32513361/1553851

Comment: @LouisWasserman Are you disputing the source, or nitpicking the question?

Comment: Not only is it not needed, it has no effect. `f` itself can be garbage-collected anyway once there are no reachable references to it, and the former value of `f.next` is still reachable via `next` and subsequently `first`. It *might* make the internal workings of GC slightly more efficient, but it is formally redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of setting `null` is to trigger earlier GC.

See, some objects could be in an old generation and if they point to objects in a new generation VM cannot reclaim those new object till full GC. VM even might be forced to propagate young objects to a long-lived object storage (eden => survival, or survival => tenured).

Minor GC might occur each second, major GC each 10 minutes. Holding an object for 10 minutes could be a dumb thing to do.

Resetting links via `null` sometimes serves for documentation purposes, like in C we write `(void) printf(...);` to denote we ignore return value.